# Using css with react

Tags: css, reactjs, react-component

So I'm just starting to learn React and I'm trying to incorporate a css file to style a react component (ie a sidebar) but I'm not sure why none of the styles show up on the webpage. I've tried inlining css in the index.js file and that works but I'm trying to move all of the styling code into a css file. I have a sass loader and css loader installed and included them in the webpack.config.js file. Am I just forgetting something dumb?

Here's my style.css file

```
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    height: 200px;
    font-size: 20;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: deepskyblue;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: azure;
}

li {
    display: block;
    color: gray;
    padding: 8px;
    font-size: 20;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li :hover {
    background-color: forestgreen;
}
```

And my index.js file

```
import React from 'react'
import {styles} from './style.css'
import Home from './home.js'

export class Sidebar extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (  
            <div className={styles.sidebar}>
                <ul>
                    <li>Home</li>
                    <li>Test1</li>
                    <li>Test2</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        )   
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm importing styles like this: `import './path/to/style/Sidebar.scss';` and `className='sidebar'`

Answer (score 0):

no need to call `styles.sidebar` as if it were an object, just import the file and assign `className` as an ordinary class....

```
import './style.css';

// [...]
<div className='sidebar'>
```

Comment: Ok changed it but why does it not change the background color?

Comment: Try just importing the file, not a named module import e.g. `import './style.css'`. Inspect the element, is the class applied in your inspector?

Comment: Yeah I can see the classname sidebar when I inspect element now but none of the elements seem to be styled

Comment: If you have the class applied, now you’ll need to modify your rules. That seems to be outside the scope of this question. Do you actually see the rules applied in your element inspector?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you have CSSLoader in your webpack.config.js file. First, let's confirm that you have something similar to me:

```
{
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          { loader: "style-loader" },
          { loader: "css-loader" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now, every time you run your webpack server, the dev bundle will include your styles in it. With that, you should be able to import css files my referencing them in the React file:

```
import './MyComponent.css'

const MyComponent = () => {...};
```

If everything is still the same, but things are still not working, I highly recommend [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app), which is a painless solution for you to focus on learning React without bothering so much with configuration details. Create React app includes amongst other things, CSS importing and Jest testing.

Comment: Yep my config file looks pretty much like that...do you think that the index.html file might be messing it up?